# How typescript genericity keys any?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to let

```
interface IBar {
  foo: IFoo;
  foo2: IFoo2;
}
```

to transform the types , because `IBar` is the dynamic `T`

```
interface IBar {
  foo: any;
  foo2: any;
}
```

my code

```
// a.ts
interface IBar {
   foo: IFoo;
   foo2: IFoo2;
}
// error is missing the following properties from type 
usePage<IBar>({ foo: ..., foo2: ... })

// b.ts
const usePage = <T extends {}>(params: T) => {
  ...
}
```

Thanks, I found the solution:

```
interface PageRenderProps<T extends any, K extends any> {
  blocks: {
    [P in keyof T]: any;
  };
  pageData: {
    [Q in keyof K]: any
  };
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand the question title. Could you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ?

```
interface IBar<T, A> {
  foo: T;
  foo2: A;
}
```

Comment: That won't work... `foo` and `foo2` are different types.

Comment: You can use two generic type ( like my edit )

Comment: There you go :)